# Ember.js RC1 - add resource dynamically / at a later stage

Tags: ember.js

In our framework we have a plug-in mechanism.  Moving from Ember.js v1.0.0-pre2 to RC1 means setting up the route mapping like so:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('contacts', function() {
        this.resource('contact', function() {
        });
    });
});
```

But let's say that we have a `Posts` module and it needs the following:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts');
});
```

Since I do not know up-front which routes will be rendered how do I build up this mapping?

Not all plug-ins are available to all users so the route mapping is rather dynamic.  In the pre2 version the route was defined in the controller and only reflected when the controller for the plug-in was included.

Comment: Discourse has some sort of dynamic building of routes but I don't know if you can add them in later: https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/routes/discourse_route.js and https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/routes/application_routes.js

Comment: @c4p: please your comment an answer and I'll accept it.  I actually downloaded the discourse code a while ago and had a look at the routeBuilder stuff but since I'm still learning Ember I didn't quite get what they were trying to do.  Makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discourse has some sort of dynamic building of routes but I don't know if you can add them in later:

`buildRoutes` defined here:

https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/routes/discourse_route.js

`buildRoutes` used here:

https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/discourse/routes/application_routes.js